# Armadillo ifftshift and ifft c++

Tags: c++, armadillo

Does anyone know how to do ifftshift + ifft (by row) for matrix in armadillo ?

I did in matlab : `ifft(ifftshift(mat,2),[],2)`;
where mat is matrix (3,18000);

I already tried to do something like in C++ :

```
arma::mat v3(3,18000); ... filled with the same values from Matlab ... 

static arma::cx_mat ifftshift(arma::cx_mat Axx)
{
    return arma::shift(arma::shift(Axx, -ceil(Axx.n_rows/2), 0), -ceil(Axx.n_cols/2), 1);
}

arma::ifft( ifftshift(v3).t() ).t();
```

**The result is not the same like in Matlab.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that your `ifftshift()` shifts in both dimensions, the matlab command is only shifting in the second (row) dimension `ifftshift(mat,2)`. Try to remove one shift in your function if you want the same behavior 
`return arma::shift(Axx,-ceil(Axx.n_cols/2),1)`.

Comment: It makes sense. But still i receive the wrong values. I double check in matlab specification, according to iffthsift definition, i am doing the same. But result are different at all.

To do ifft by row, is it okay to use double transpose ? 
 arma::ifft( ifftshift(v3).t() ).t();

Comment: According to arma::ifft() doc: "If given a matrix, the transform is done on each column vector of the matrix" so it should in that case be transposed before.

Comment: Yes. I did it : ifftshift(v3).t() , and after that i transformed the matrix to original size with the second ".t()". I still didn't find the reason why i do not have the same value as Matlab code.

Comment: Check if there is a problem with complex conjugates. The [.t() function](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#t_st_members) is Hermitian transpose (signs of imaginary elements are flipped). A simple transpose is done using the [.st() function](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#t_st_members), where no signs are flipped.

Comment: @ClaesRolen i would like how can is possible to avoid .t() because is time costs for me ? Should i start to fill the  matrix 'mat' with (18000,3); I mean to change the column with rows ?